# white space appears on right side of page at a screen width of 745px

Tags: html, css

I'm doing the media queries and I noticed when the screen is at a width of 745px a small gap of white space appears on the right side of the screen. I've hovered over it from top to bottom and can't find any elements sticking out? I also have one media query at 745px and that's not the issue? Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you:) 
https://jsfiddle.net/4av5mq13/

```js
const ham = document.querySelector('.nav-box');
const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
const menuClose = document.querySelector('#menu-close');
const leftArrow = document.querySelector('#left');
const rightArrow = document.querySelector('#right');
const img = document.querySelector('.image-slider');
let num = 1;


ham.addEventListener('click', function() {
 ham.classList.add('ham-open');
 menu.style.marginLeft = '50px';
})

menuClose.addEventListener('click', function() {
 ham.classList.remove('ham-open');
 menu.style.marginLeft = '-700px';
})

leftArrow.addEventListener('click', function() {
 num--;
 if(num > 0) {
  img.style.backgroundImage = 'url(img/fam-' + num + '.jpeg)';
  console.log(num);
  console.log(img.style.backgroundImage);
 } else {
  num = 4;
  img.style.backgroundImage = 'url(img/fam-' + num + '.jpeg)';
 }
})

rightArrow.addEventListener('click', function() {
 num++;
 if(num <= 4) {
  img.style.backgroundImage = 'url(img/fam-' + num + '.jpeg)';
  console.log(num);
  console.log(img.style.backgroundImage);
 } else {
  num = 1;
  img.style.backgroundImage = 'url(img/fam-' + num + '.jpeg)';
 } 
})

// window.sr = ScrollReveal();

// sr.reveal('.logo-wrap', {
//  duration: 2000
// });

// sr.reveal('.w1', {
//  duration: 2000,
//  origin: 'bottom'
// });

// sr.reveal('.w2', {
//  duration: 3000,
//  origin: 'bottom'
// });

// sr.reveal('.w3', {
//  duration: 4000,
//  origin: 'bottom'
// });

// sr.reveal('.hours-line-left', {
//  duration: 1000,
//  origin: 'left',
//  distance: '200px'
// });

// sr.reveal('.hours-line-right', {
//  duration: 1000,
//  origin: 'right',
//  distance: '200px'
// });

// sr.reveal('.contact-line', {
//  duration: 1000,
//  origin: 'bottom',
//  distance: '250px'
// });

// sr.reveal('.burrito', {
//  duration: 1000,
//  origin: 'right',
//  distance: '250px'
// });

// sr.reveal('.taco', {
//  duration: 1000,
//  origin: 'right',
//  distance: '250px'
// });

// sr.reveal('.guac', {
//  duration: 1000,
//  origin: 'right',
//  distance: '250px'
// });

// sr.reveal('.nachos', {
//  duration: 1000,
//  origin: 'bottom',
//  distance: '250px'
// });

// sr.reveal('.hot', {
//  duration: 1000,
//  origin: 'left',
//  distance: '250px'
// });

// sr.reveal('.back-to-top', {
//  duration: 1000,
//  origin: 'bottom',
// });

// sr.reveal('.btp-arrow', {
//  duration: 1500,
//  origin: 'top',
//  distance: '250px'
// });
```

Comment: provide a working snippet

Comment: Can't I have too much code that's why I posted the fiddle link

Answer (score 0):

`.map` and `#right` are overflowing the right sides of their ancestors at that viewport width.

Add this rule:

```
.image-slider-wrap,
body>footer {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: How come then when I hover over #right or .map I don't see it sticking out? How did you find them overflowing??

Comment: Furthermore When I shift those elements to the left the white space doesn't disappear?

Comment: Relative positioning doesn't move where an element takes up space, it just moves where it appears to be. I used the DOM Inspector to give elements `display:none` one at a time to starting from the children of `body` to see which were overflowing. An alternative technique is to apply an outline to all block-level elements.

Comment: It doesn't work https://jsfiddle.net/3v1wsm5n/ and adding that property hides the 'back to top' text that sits right above the footer and below the back to top arrow

Comment: A better solution would be to remove the `right: -20px` declaration for `.food-wrap` and give `overflow:hidden` to `body > footer .location`. You probably also want to do something to allow "Authentic Mexican Food" to wrap or reduce its font-size for narrow viewports.